# NetLogo - Distributing grains of sand in sandpile model to random neighbours

Tags: netlogo

This code relates to an adaption of the NetLogo sandpile model. When the count go grains in each patch exceeds the threshold which in this case is 3, the grains are re-distributed to the surrounding neighbors.  I am trying to re-distribute one grain to 4 random neighbour patches.

The code returns a run time error because patches at the edge will not have all the 8 neighbors, so when asking for 4 random neighbours it returns an errors stating can't request 4 ransom agents from 3 etc.

I am trying to find a piece of code that will resolve this problem.

****Code Below*****

```
to-report stabilize [animate?]
  let active-patches patches with [ n > threshold ]

  ;; The number iterations the avalanche has gone for. Use to calculate lifetimes.
  let iters 0

  ;; we want to count how many patches became overloaded at some point
  ;; during the avalanche, and also flash those patches. so as we go, we'll
  ;; keep adding more patches to to this initially empty set.
  let avalanche-patches no-patches

  while [ any? active-patches ] [
    let overloaded-patches active-patches with [ n > threshold ]
    if any? overloaded-patches [
      set iters iters + 1

    ]
    ask overloaded-patches [
      set base-color fired-color
      ;; subtract 'threshold' amount from this patch
      update-n -4
      if animate? [ recolor ]
      ;; edge patches have less than four neighbors, so some sand may fall off the edge
      ask n-of 4 neighbors [
        update-n 1
        if animate? [ recolor ]
      ]
    ]
    if animate? [ display ]
    ;; add the current round of overloaded patches to our record of the avalanche
    ;; the patch-set primitive combines agentsets, removing duplicates
    set avalanche-patches (patch-set avalanche-patches overloaded-patches)
    ;; find the set of patches which *might* be overloaded, so we will check
    ;; them the next time through the loop
    set active-patches patch-set [ neighbors ] of overloaded-patches
  ]
  report (list avalanche-patches iters)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of asking 4 neighbors, ask `min list 4 count neighbors`:

```
ask n-of (min list 4 count neighbors) neighbors [ 
  ... 
]
```

But from the model point of view, there will be different redistribution on the edge of the table, so this is not a good idea. Maybe it is better to have a wrapped world and then manually "push" the grains off the table: select 4 neighbours and call just the ones with close pxcor and pycor. The rest is off the table.

If the world is wrapped (horizontally and vertically), we can always select 4 neighbors:

```
let selected-neighbors n-of 4 neighbors
```

Among these 4 neighbors only real neighbors are on the table

```
set selected-neighbors selected-neighbors with [ 
  (abs (pxcor - [ pxcor ]  of myself) < 2) 
  and
  (abs (pycor - [ pycor ]  of myself) < 2) 
  ] 

ask selected-neighbors [
 ....
 ]
```